# Curve fitting with optimization.curve_fit jumping around all over the place

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have two arrays of calculated values, named `xvals` and `yvals`. I know the functional form these the data points should lie along, so I know the result I should get. I should get an x^4 curve, however when I let python calculate and plot the best fit, the line jumps around between all the data points! Here's what I tried so far:

```
def func(x, a, b, c, d, e):
    return a - b*x - c*x**2 - d*x**3 - e*x**4

fita, fitb = optimization.curve_fit(func, xvals, yvals)

#--stuff to initialize a matplotlib plot goes here blah blah blah--

plt.scatter(xvals, yvals, marker='o', c=cparam, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis'), s=100, zorder=2)
plt.plot(xvals, func(xvals, *fita), 'r-')
```

The curve fitting returns the correct coefficients for a, b, c, d, and e. As you can see, the new fit line seems to jump around between all of the data points when plotted. I think this has something to do with the x-values being out of order, however if I order them it would potentially mess up plotting the scatter plot. I tried making a new independent set of evenly spaced x-values and calculated some corresponding y-values and plotting that, but the line disappears from my plot. Am I missing something to get this to behave better?

[image: The weird fit]

Comment: For a line plot it is necessary that the `xvals` appear in incrementing order. You could try `xvals = np.sort(xvals)`. You could also draw a smooth curve using `xs = np.linspace(xvals.min()-0.5, xvals.max()+0.5, 500)`